# Libcurl Vs. TidHttp on Delphi?

Tags: delphi, http, cookies, curl, https

I would like to perform http operations (GET,POST,SSL,cookies,proxies,http auth handling) and I'm looking for what's best between Libcurl for Delphi and TIdHttp. Any direction?

Thx for your help,

Stephane

Comment: Are you using Libcurl with Delphi?

Comment: I've been using IXMLHTTPRequest from MSXML2_TLB which works really great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TIdHttp was made for Delphi and the main target language for Libcurl is C.

Comment: That does not mean that libcurl cannot be used in Delphi, though.  C libraries work well in Delphi.  Some might argue that libcurl's API would be simpler to use.  Either one will be able to handle Stephane's requirements, though.